# Letter visualisation in TilePane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, character, letter

**What I need to do:**

I trying to write some code for visualise every pixel of any character. I decided best way for it will be show pixels as rectangle in Tile Pane. So this is effect which i need to reach:

[image]

**What's my problem:**

I wrote some code to make it by take snaphost of `text1` and save it as `WritableImage`. Then i use `PixelReader` for read each pixel of this image by `argb` method. In loop when each integer rgb value is greater than TRESHOLD (is brighter) I add new tile with white background. Unless I add tile with black background. But something is still wrong with my idea and I get this effect:

[image]

**There is my code:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        //Create single letter string
        String letter = "a";
        //Create new text
        Text text1 = new Text(letter);
        //Set font for text
        text1.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.NORMAL, 12));

        //Save text1 as writable image
        WritableImage newImg = text1.snapshot(null, null);

        //Take bounds of letter
        int imgHeight = (int) newImg.getHeight();
        int imgWidth = (int) newImg.getWidth();

        //Create pixel reader from newImg
        PixelReader reader = newImg.getPixelReader();

        //This is for preview image
        ImageView imgPreview = new ImageView(newImg);

        //Create tilePane
        TilePane tilePane = new TilePane();
        //New group with tilePane inside
        Group display = new Group(tilePane);

        //Bg color
        tilePane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray;");
        //Small gaps between tiles
        tilePane.setHgap(2);
        tilePane.setVgap(2);

        //Set quantity of columns equals image width
        tilePane.setPrefColumns(imgWidth);
        //Set quantity of rows equals image height
        tilePane.setPrefRows(imgHeight );

        //Here I set tolerance treshold
        int TOLERANCE_THRESHOLD = 0xf0;


        for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {

                int argb = reader.getArgb(x, y);

                int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;
                int g = (argb >> 8) & 0xFF;
                int b = argb & 0xFF;

                if (r >= TOLERANCE_THRESHOLD
                        && g >= TOLERANCE_THRESHOLD
                        && b >= TOLERANCE_THRESHOLD) {
                    tilePane.getChildren().add(createElement(Color.WHITE));
                }
                else tilePane.getChildren().add(createElement(Color.BLACK));

            }
        }

        // Create new stage
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        //Create new group
        Group grupa = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(grupa, 400, 300, Color.GRAY);

        grupa.getChildren().addAll(display);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Rectangle createElement(Color color) {
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(15, 15);
        //rectangle.setStroke(Color.ORANGE);
        rectangle.setFill(color);

        return rectangle;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

What I doing wrong? Maby are other ways to take this effect?

Comment: Nice project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your outer loop variable is the x-coordinate and the inner loop variable is the y-coordinate.

This means you read the pixels column by column left to right. `TilePane` however requires the children list to be ordered row by row from top to bottom.

To fix the issue simply swap the loops. Use:

```
for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
for (int x = 0; x < imgWidth; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < imgHeight; y++) {
        ...
    }
}
```