# How read some text by PixelReader

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on [this project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745356/letter-visualisation-in-tilepane-in-javafx) now. I used there `snapshot` method on object of `Text` class. Then I'm able to use `PixelReader` class for read every pixel of `WritableImage`. On the right is image of letter created by `snapshot` method, and on the left is pixel visualisation of this letter.

[image]

My problem is that quality of image on the right is very poor (it's raster graphics). Is any way to convert `String` or `Text` object into image which is vector graphics and then use on it pixel reader?

I'm sorry if my questions are basics, but I'm new in Java. Maby are other possibilities to make this effect from picture better ? Thanks for every advice.

Comment: IDK if there is an easy way to do this, but I doubt it. But why don't you use a scale transform for the snapshot instead of a image that scaled by a factor of something between 15 to 17?

Comment: I actually found appropriate way to achieve my target with using of `Graphics2D` class.